# Неизвестная ошибка в php коде

Tags: php, mysql, функции, mysqli, php7.2

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'qwerty123', 'mecom');
if ($connect == false) { exit(); }
mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES utf8");

function read_sql ($org) {
    $arr = array();
    while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($org)) {
        array_push($arr, $res);
    }
    return $arr;
}

$products_org = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `category_id` = '$category[id]'");
$products = read_sql($products_org);

echo "string";
```

Вызов функции "read_sql" выдает fatal error (по крайней мере "string" не выводится). Никак не могу найти, в чем ошибка.

Comment: `read_sql ($org)` а итерация по `$arr`. Может сначала разберетесь в своем коде?

Comment: Разобрался. Все равно не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в передаче параметра в запрос

```
$param = $category['id'];
$products_org = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `category_id` = '$param'");
```

Comment: До этого уже записывается массив "$category". Но проблема в том, что записывается он также этой функцией. Так что я уверен, что броблема в самой функции.

Comment: Как извлекается значения по ключу из массива? Наверное `$category['id']` так, а не так `$category[id]`. У Вас ошибка в синтаксисе.